# DEBEZIUM. Cannot ALTER table because field is not optional but has no default value

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Short info about system:

1. Target Postgres db with data. For this DB need to add CDC Debezium
2. Kafka connect with zookepeer and debezium connector for change data capture.
3. Source connector PostgreSQL. It's working fine and properly sends data to kafka connect.
4. Sink connector for consume messages from kafka and insert it to destination PostgreSQL database

My sink connector config properties:

```
{
    "name": "sink-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics.regex": "public.*",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/db",
        "connection.username": "postgres",
        "connection.password": "postgres",
        "insert.mode": "insert",
        "table.name.format": "${topic}",
        "primary.key.mode": "none",
        "schema.evolution": "basic",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true"
    }
}
```

When I add sink connector to kafka connect then I get this error:
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot ALTER table '[TableName]' because field '[PrimaryKeyOfTable]' is not optional but has no default value`
After adding connector destination table has been added to database, but only with one row. And this behavior is same for other tables.

Data in kafka broker:

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "..."
                    },
                    /* List of fields */
                ],
                "optional": true,
                "name": "...",
                "field": "before"
            },
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "...."
                    },
                    /* List of fields */
                ],
                "optional": true,
                "name": "...",
                "field": "after"
            },
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "version"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "connector"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "name"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "ts_ms"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "name": "io.debezium.data.Enum",
                        "version": 1,
                        "parameters": {
                            "allowed": "true,last,false,incremental"
                        },
                        "default": "false",
                        "field": "snapshot"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "db"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "sequence"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "schema"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "table"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "txId"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "lsn"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "xmin"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": false,
                "name": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source",
                "field": "source"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": false,
                "field": "op"
            },
            {
                "type": "int64",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "ts_ms"
            },
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "id"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "total_order"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "data_collection_order"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": true,
                "name": "event.block",
                "version": 1,
                "field": "transaction"
            }
        ],
        "optional": false,
        "name": "public.[TableName].Envelope",
        "version": 1
    },
    "payload": {
        "before": null,
        "after": {
            "Column1": 1,
            "Column2": "Val1"
            /* List of column names and its values */
        },
        "source": {
            "version": "2.3.0.Final",
            "connector": "postgresql",
            "name": "db",
            "ts_ms": 1689113287151,
            "snapshot": "false",
            "db": "postgres",
            "sequence": "[\"29921128\",\"29921128\"]",
            "schema": "public",
            "table": "[TableName]",
            "txId": 788,
            "lsn": 29921128,
            "xmin": null
        },
        "op": "u",
        "ts_ms": 1689113287337,
        "transaction": null
    }
}
```

I tried:

- Added table to database and set "schema.evolution" to "none", but I got error "Could not find table".
- Added params "transforms", I got error "(struct) type doesn't have a mapping to the sql database column type"
- Set "primary.key.mode" : "record_value" (also use value "record_key") and "primary.key.fields" : "{PKFieldName}" (I mean my real column name, not inline param).
- Plus, I do not remember what I have done, but I got this error message: "cross-database references are not implemented"

I want to see that CDC data in kafka broker will be consume and save in destination PostgreSQL Db.

Answer (score 1):

Debezium creates tables with mask: "{table_prefix}.{table_schema}.{table_name}". And it was main problem. To fix it you should add param  "quote.identifiers": "true"